# Почему у меня все ссылки отображаются в строку по дефолту?

Tags: html, css

Самое странное, что после указания display: flex; они отображаются столбиком. Кто-нибудь знает как это исправить?
код html:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="">12</a>
    <a href="">12</a>
    <a href="">21</a>
</div>
```

код css :

```
body, html{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: white;
}

.content {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: lightblue;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Может это из-за open server'а?

Comment: Где вообще стили для ссылок, почему они должны располагаться как-то иначе? Кому вы поставили `display: flex`?

Comment: Для ссылок нету стилей, поэтому я и спрашиваю, ссылки должны отображаться столбиком, разве нет ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег `a` является строчным элементом, поэтому по умолчанию он будет в строку отображаться, [вот здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/type/inline) можно посмотреть все строчные элементы.

Если вам нужно изменить стиль отображения, Вы уже сами ответили на вопрос, нужно поменять свойство `display`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `<a>` это строчный элемент.

Когда ты им указываешь `display: flex`; Они становятся блоками, а блоки как известно занимают всю строк, по этому каждый на своей строке.

Используй `dislpay: flex; flex-direction: row;` (Для строки)
или `dislpay: flex; flex-direction: column;` (Для для колонки)

Данный атрибут необходимо указывать родителю (`.header`), а не дочерним элементам (`а`).